# Where can I write a temp file from ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have an 'access denied' problem on an ASP.NET web application, where the user uploads an Excel file and I try and write it to a folder.  I don't have access to the host except FTP, so I can't set permissions.  I thought that ASP.NET would be able to write to a folder that is under the web app root, but it isn't so.

Is there anywhere I can write the file to that doesn't require me to set permissions?

Comment: I use shared hosting with a few different companies, and I am allowed to set permissions on folders.  You should look into this further with the tech support department of your host.

Comment: @Cen, it's not an issue of being allowed to set permissions or not, but rather that at this time I only have FTP access to my client's host server.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

ASP.NET can write to a folder if the account under which it is running (the application pool user) has write permissions on it.

If this is indeed a temporary file, you can get a filename from the `Path` class using [`GetTempFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx):

```
string tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
```

You can use this in conjunction with [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts8hk0.aspx) to be sure you have permissions to write to a folder.

Comment: You can find the Path class in System.IO